# Need a minimalistic jQuery gallery without thumbnails

Tags: jquery, gallery

I'm pulling my hair out trying to find a simple jquery gallery. I must be having a mental block because this has been far harder than it should be! The gallery needs to be very simple, with the following things:

- No thumbnails
- Not in a lightbox
- Click image to go to next slide
- Previous/next buttons
- Basically reproducing the functionality of the slideshow found on this website: http://cargocollective.com/akacreatives#1406517/Ned
- Need to be able to have multiple instances of the gallery on one long page (I'm using scrollTo on a long vertical page for a portfolio and each section of the page will have its own gallery)

I **know** there are plugins out there that do this, but the ONLY things I seem to be able to find are ones which require the use of thumbnails to function properly. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made one just for you, :-)

Took ten minutes, and not tested at all, but should work with some minor adjustments, and it's super simple.

It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pQawc/1/

Comment: What took 3 hours of unsuccessful toil for me took 10 minutes for you. Cheers mate, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The cycle plugin is great:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Satisfies all your criteria except clicking the image to advance but that is an easy fix. You will do something like:

```
$('#img-container').click(function(){ 
  $('#img-container').cycle('next'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the lightbox I wrote: https://github.com/felixhagspiel/jsOnlyLightbox

You can dynamically push images and create separate groups to simulate multiple instances (or just create seperate instances of it), it supports your other requirements as well. I am just not sure about the part "Not in a lightbox", but you can customize the CSS of it to display it somehow different